# How to add a character to EditText in the beginning when typing

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to add a '+' to an editText field when people enter their phone number. However I can't seem to get it to add a '+' with this code.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_edit_phone);

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable text) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (text.length() == 0) {
                text.append('+');
            }
        }
    });
```

What should I change to make it work?

Comment: when does text.length() ever == 0 after text changed? ... plus why are you using text.length() when you created a string called mStr?

Comment: do you want it to add after user focus on edittext or not?

Comment: @masoudvali I want it to add after user focus on edittext yes

Comment: @DroiDev sorry I removed the mStr it was from previous code. And I put textLength()==0 because when the text length is 0, I want there to be a '+' so everything the user types in afterwards is added after that '+'. But that's also where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will add constant + at start of your `EditText`. Which user can not clear.

```
        final EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final String prefix = "+";
        editText.setText(prefix);
        Selection.setSelection(editText.getText(), editText.getText().length());
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (!s.toString().startsWith(prefix)) {
                    editText.setText(prefix);
                    Selection.setSelection(editText.getText(), editText.getText().length());
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

on onTextChanged put below code

`edittext.setText(“+”.concat(ediitext.getText());`